# PCL recompose point clouds of a flipped object

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am trying to recompose (register) two point clouds of the same object with PCL (C++, VS2019). I am a bit stuck and I was wondering if someone has an idea on how to solve my problem. I have these two point clouds, two sides of the same object (flipped on one side). I am trying to properly register the two sides in one merged cloud, without any success.
I thought that maybe bounding boxes could help in the process...
Any idea? Thanks!

The points clouds once segmented and filtered:

[image: The points clouds once segmented and filtered:]

Just two show the two shells of the same egg to be clear:)

[image: Just two show the two shells of the same egg:)]

Comment: Can you flip them manually, then use ICP/Ransac?

Comment: Hello @Stef thanks for your comment. Ideally, I won't be able to flip them manually since I have a lot of them to process in my workflow. If by "manually" you intend a geometrical transformation of the point cloud. In fact, the orientation of the two point clouds are unknown and can vary.